# SharePoint 2013 Load Testing

Tags: 2013, visual-studio, load-testing

All

I am sure this topic has been discussed in  a few occasions, but I am still unsure what route I should take.

I need to prove that our sharepoint farm is performant enough for x users.

I started recording web performance tests in VS 2013 Ultimate, such as File upload, view home page, view a wiki page. I am planning to generate load test by using these web performance tests.

My question is that. Whether it is a correct way to approach this problem. If so, what type of other tests you have recorded/performed to prove your farm performance? Any information any source will be apreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple test in VS to get the content of a web page. However many of those tests only gather the HTML response and not all of the files which come along. We started first with those simple tests. A small exe triggered by VisualCron and then we analysed the resultes. As said, the results tended to be too optimistic. Finally we ended up using Selenium (http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) which is in fact browser automation. In this way you can get the full picture.